# Is there any way of knowing whether downloaded the song through Apple Music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, media

I'm trying to understand, can I check whether MPMediaItem song from Apple Music downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to check it, but it's kind of hacky.

If the MPMediaItem has the MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork object, that means that the song is downloaded to the device. Streamed Apple Music songs don't have this artwork object. I filed a radar for this because I believe that the artwork should be added onto the MPMediaItem, but for now this should do the trick for you.

You can duplicate the bugreport if you want: 25413082

Comment: @John do you mean that streamed songs now also return album art?

Comment: @John can you share how you've tested this? I've just built a test application and I'm still seeing the same behaviour.